# error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Line' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Im getting the error in my Document.cpp constructor:

```
Document::Document() {
    this->lines = new ListImp<Line>();
}
```

The Document.h attributes:

```
protected:
    List<Line> *lines;
```

Comment: The code you posted isn't related to the failure

Comment: @icepack The thing is, i really dont know where is the failure.

Comment: Look in ListImp's constructor and the functions it calls. The error message should have continuation lines that give more details.

Comment: double click error and you will get to exact location of error